# Sql group by sum of each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
C1          C2      C3  C4              C5   C6    
INTERESES   40530   5   050405011232011 2013  5    
PRINCIPAL   40529   5   050405011232011 2016  3    
PRINCIPAL   40530   5   050405011232011 2013  4
```

And i need to group this rows by C1, C3 and C4 and return in the cases of lane 2 and 3 the C2 column with the max C5. I mean in this case this should return:

```
C1          C2      C3  C4              C5
INTERESES   40530   5   050405011232011 5
PRINCIPAL   40529   5   050405011232011 7
```

The second row should have 40529 in the column C2 cause it have the biggest value in the C5 column.
The C5 column should have the sum of the C6 of the previous table.

How can i do this? Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of aggregation, one method uses window functions:

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4, sum_c5
from (select t.*,
             sum(c5) over (partition by c1, c3, c4) as sum_c5,
             row_number() over (partition by c1, c3, c4 order by c5 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Oracle also has `keep` syntax with allows you to get the "first" value in an aggregation:

```
select c1, 
       max(c2) keep (dense_rank first order by c5 desc) as c2,
       c3, c4,
       sum(c5)
from t
group by c1, c3, c4;
```

Comment: It works but i have a little problem i need to sum a column too. I explain in the op. Can yo please help me if i sum this it only apply to one row

Comment: @AbelJuanRodríguez . . . Use the second version with `sum(c5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.c1, t.c2, t.c3, t.c4
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where c1 = t.c1 and c2 = t.c2 and c3 = t.c3 and c5 > t.c5 
)
```